# .htaccess - how to force "www." in a generic way?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This will change `domain.example` to `www.domain.example`:

```
# Force the "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `http://www.domain.example/$1` [R=301,L]
```

How do I replace the "domain" part so that this works on *any* domain?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

I would use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The first condition checks whether the *Host* value is not empty (in case of HTTP/1.0); the second checks whether the the *Host* value does not begin with `www.`; the third checks for HTTPS (`%{HTTPS}` is either `on` or `off`, so `%{HTTPS}s` is either `ons` or `offs` and in case of `ons` the `s` is matched). The substitution part of `RewriteRule` then just merges the information parts to a full URL.

Comment: This solution works only if you want all sub-domains forwarded to www.yourdomain.com. If you only want to force www, you should update the second line to be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]`

Comment: I don't get _any_ of my subdomains forwarded to www.mydomain.com using the rule posted in the question...

Comment: very clever! I like you forced the HTTPS check to return an "S" in the capture group, which you used on the following line. very elegant

Comment: Seems Like a Universal answer , covers HTTPs and normal protocols, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! I would add `RewriteEngine On` as the first line to complete it, as this could lead to a 500 Server Error if copy-pasted as it is.

Comment: @BaldEagle That edit should never have been approved. It didn't improve the answer (solving that issue would have), instead it should've been a comment. Also it's actually not an issue. This works perfectly fine for such URLs.

Answer (score 48):

This will do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect all non-www requests to your site to the www version, all you need to do is add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work with subdomains.

`domain.example` correctly gets redirected to `www.domain.example`

but

`images.domain.example` gets redirected to `www.images.domain.example`

Instead of checking if the subdomain is "not www", check if there are two dots:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ HTTP%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I like this solution. Anyway to accomplish the same thing with TLDs like .co.uk?

Comment: @iUseMagentoNow just increase the dots, for example: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]` (Strictly speaking, your TLD is still `.uk` and your domain is `something.co`.)

Comment: .co in this case is a second level domain and is not actually a part of your domain where as .uk is a country code TLD. To be honest, having worked in the hosting industry and seeing the new formats for domain names i cant see the current TLD formats lasting for anything other than official uses. goverments, organisations etc. In the near future when you can register fqdn like, fred.bloggs for a similar price to current norms then the personal web will look very different from a DNS point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The following should prefix 'www' to any request that doesn't have one, and redirect the edited request to the new URI.

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www\."         [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "(.*)"
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "http://www.%1$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

This redirects `example.com` to `www.example.com` excluding subdomains.

Comment: For me this seems to be sending www.example.com to www.www.example.com haha

Comment: @Albert Perhaps this is because of your browser cache. Clear your cache and Retry.

Comment: You are correct! I just ran in incognito (chrome) and it worked fine, thanks!

Comment: I like this generic rule very much. But it doesn`t work for http://domain.co.uk  as it already has two dots in it. How could this rule be changed to make it work for .co.uk as well?

Comment: For .co.uk and other sub cctlds this works:
^([^.]+\.[^.]+)(\.(uk|ar|cy|ar|tr))?$
but unfortunately there are some mixed typed tlds (https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List)
like es that allow domain.es as well as domain.com.es. Adding |es to the regex would match domain.es as well as www.domain.es which is not wanted here. Have to find a way to handle this mixed typed sub-cctlds

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, and there are many different ways to do this. The most complete answer, IMHO, is found here: https://gist.github.com/vielhuber/f2c6bdd1ed9024023fe4 . (Pasting and formatting the code here didn't work for me)

Answer (score -1):

this worked like magic for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.example/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```