# htaccess: how to force www in a generic way

Tags: apache, .htaccess

RE: [.htaccess - how to force "www." in a generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way)

I asked this question before, and got this answer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It works, but now I am seeing `301 Moved Permanently` in the response headers. I want to eliminate the 301s. Is the problem the 2nd rewrite condition? Should it be something like "does not start with 'www.' followed by the host name"?

By the way, I want this solution to work for any server (meaning, I don't want to hard code my domain name).

Suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that the above is not working correctly. If I have the following:

`http://images.domain.com`

I don't want that to change to:

`http://www.images.domain.com`

I don't want this affecting sub-domains. I only want it to affect missing `www`.

Comment: Re making the solution work on any server, it should do that already, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Pekka, this one does. I just wanted to tell the experts here so that they don't provide me with an answer that involves hard coding my domain name.

Comment: @Stack well, I think what you want to do can't be done. Why is the 301 a problem?

Comment: How do you plan to perform the redirect without telling the browser about it?

Comment: @Pekka - two of my 301 redirects cost about 260ms (images). The other one cost about 520ms (CSS). I'm trying to see what I can do to optimize the speed of the site.

Comment: @Stack 260ms for a redirect? That sounds odd. But why do they happen in the first place - why do you have image and CSS links pointing to the undesired server address?

Comment: @Pekka, say the image is at http://images.domain.com/logo.gif. What's happening is that it's changing to http://www.images.domain.com/logo.gif. There's a bug in the rewrite condition, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting to a different domain is by definition not possible without *some* header redirect. If you want the URL in the user's browser to change, you have to force a new request. There is no way around that.

You will have [to take your pick](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - the `301`, `302` and `303` status codes being the most straight forward choices.

Comment: I've updated my question with an additional problem. Are you able to help? I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: @StackOverflow an additional `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$` would fix it but that would bind it to specific domains. As to how to exclude `images.*`, maybe ask Gumbo in the other question, he knows more about this stuff

Comment: do you know how I can make the rule say "does not begin with a www followed by a dot followed by the HTTP HOST"? That's the only time I think I want to rewrite.

Comment: @Stack mmm, if I'm not mistaken, if I have `www.` in front, then HTTP_HOST consists of www. plus the main domain name, doesn't it?

Comment: ohh! You are right! This has become a bigger headache, I think.