# different session with url's with-www and without-www

Tags: php, session, url

I have a interactive web site that has authors.
When an author enters the site on www.mysite.com and logs in, the session varible becomes

```
$_SESSION[loggedid]=true;
```

and site-theme changes.

But when he enters mysite.com (without www's) even he is logged in, he sees the default theme, can't write etc.
I think they are different sessions, am i right? Is it depends on my server or browser or what? How can i make this 2, same sessions or redirect the user's from one to one?

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly legit solution and widely used. OP said "... or redirect the user's from one to one?"

Comment: Downvote without comment? Enforcing a specific domain solves the problem and actually helps seo!

Comment: These lines solve not only the problem but redirects mysite.com to www.mysite.com in all cases.

Comment: Thanks AlienWebguy for your help. It solved my issue :)

Comment: Cleaner solution is found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way

Comment: Would have taken you less time and would have been more helpful to everybody if you'd have just edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's RewriteRule

`^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`

and not

`$1 [R=permanent,L]`.

If you add `.com$1 [R=permanent,L]` in **php.ini** and you try *mysite.com/index.php?id=934* it redirects you to *mysite.comindex.php/?id934*

Answer (score 1):

Use this: https://www.php.net/session_set_cookie_params
To set the domain to match all subdomains do this:

```
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, '/', '.domain.com');
```

You need to use that before a calling session_start().

You could use this code example taken straight from the link above, which let's you keep all the current settings except the domain:

```
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 

$rootDomain = '.example.com'; 

session_set_cookie_params( 
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
    $currentCookieParams["path"], 
    $rootDomain, 
    $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
); 

session_name('mysessionname'); 
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your [`session.cookie_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) to the domain `.yourdomainname.tld`, note the starting dot (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

```
session.cookie_domain =
```

php.ini directive

try using

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

that leading dot means session will affect every domain. Be aware of SUHOSHIN! Sometimes it restricts this function!