# Sessions break when www prefixed to url

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

How do I fix this problem with $_SESSION variables?

Session variables are present when I am on `http://www.example.com`, and run this code:

```
echo 'Printing session variables: <br><br><pre>';
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";
echo '</pre>';
```

However, if I am on `http://example.com`, there are no session variables.

How can I make it so that $_SESSIONs work the same, regardless whether `www.` is prefixed or not?

**I would like the site to default to `http://example.com`, not to `http://www.example.com`**

Comment: It may be a duplucate.  Refer here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784654/different-session-with-urls-with-www-and-without-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `The Guest`'s comment, I found the correct solution to using an `.htaccess` file to re-write the URI so that `www` prefix is re-written to the non-www form, which is a slight variation on the top-rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784654/different-session-with-urls-with-www-and-without-www/6784672#6784672):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784654/different-session-with-urls-with-www-and-without-www/6784672#6784672) defaults to the `www.example.com` URI form; above variation defaults everything to the **`non-www`** URI form.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is add a line to the .htaccess file to force the urls be using either the www. or no www.