# Best way to force WWW with PHP and not HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to force WWW. into my domain name, but by using PHP vs. HTACCESS like I have below. Is there any issues by doing it with PHP vs. HTACCESS?
Does anyone have any code on how to set this up in the best possible manor?

```
#for all requests on mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.ca$ [NC]
#if they are not for the www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.ca$ [NC]
#301 redirect to www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For enforcing www in your url, if possible `.htaccess` should be your choice. It will give you better performance!! Anyway, if you really want to use php code for this you can use following code snippet:

```
if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.') === false))
{
    header('Location: http://www.'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

For more generic `.htaccess` redirect code would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Here is  the reference

1. [htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958847/1289495)
2. [PHP redirect](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/use-php-to-force-the-www-on-urls/)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. The HTACCESS Generic, that works even better.... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$domain= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$uri=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
if($domain == "example.com"){
    header("Location: www.example.com$uri");
}
```