# Images are not showing up

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on fixing a website.

Images don't show up unless the url starts with `www`

For example when you try to access this image `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/VictorMoreTrimed.jpg`, it redirects you to the home page.

With the `www` in front, it shows up.

I tried to edit the `.htaccess` file to redirect the whole website to the `www` version:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks 
    RewriteEngine on 
    rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc] 
    rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [r=301,nc]
```

But it still not working.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Happy to look at it, Mahmoud. But would highly recommend changing your links to `example.com` for two reasons: first, many people will worry about clicking an unknown link (which might capture their location etc); second, a moderator may look at the links as spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provided your entire htaccess, we can try inserting some lines to force `www` on all your pages.

```
#DirectoryIndex 
index.php 
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# Insert here to force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# End of forcing www

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Reference:

[How to force “www.” in a generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way)

Comment: Hi zx81 , thank you . but unfortunately I tried it and it did not work .Maybe there is a delay or something ?

Comment: Is there anything else in your htaccess? It sounds like there is a rule somewhere that redirects to the home page in certain conditions. Or are there rules somewhere in other code?

Comment: Well , this is the other code in my htaccess file #DirectoryIndex index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
it's WordPress common code

Comment: Thanks for providing your htaccess. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you . Your code works , but not with the images on the homepage !!
This is weird !

Comment: for example it **works with this one http://vivahealthylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/BookAppointmentOnLine.jpg **
 but **not with this one  http://vivahealthylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/VictorMoreTrimed.jpg **

Comment: Are you able to check on your server if the file name is capitalized exactly that way? We seem to be hitting the `!-f ` condition.

Comment: I think it was my browser cache or a delay . Everything works great now , thank you

Comment: It was pleasure to communicate with you . Thank you very much , I hope to meet you again

Comment: Likewise, Mahmoud... See you next time! :)