# How to force www. with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www, public-html

I have looked around and no one seems to be experiencing the same problem as me.

I have used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However when I navigate to `yoursite.com` I get taken to `www.yoursite.com/public_html` which doesn't exist.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/
| .htaccess
|
| public_html
    |
    |index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this line :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
```

[Gumbo in his answer (how to force “www.” in a generic way?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way) recommanded this structure :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is move the `.htaccess` file to the `public_html` folder.

Comment: My htaccess has other directives within it. I have cache control, gzipping and IP blocks. Will any of that break if I move it?