# www. to non-www redirect Correct Laravel way

Tags: .htaccess, url, laravel-5, url-rewriting

First of all the question has already been asked in different form here:

[Redirect www to non-www in Laravel with URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754119/redirect-www-to-non-www-in-laravel-with-url-parameters)

However, there are some untouched concerns:

1. Is it good enough to redirect, without specifying the status code (Like 301, Moved permanently)?
2. Would it be better to consider using middleware as suggested here: http://byjml.com/force-laravel-traffic-to-www/ ?

or

3. Would it better to use classic .htaccess redirect, with [L,301]?

Comment: I would be inclined to use .htaccess for this because I'm of the opinion that the application code should not be concerned with the domain it runs under. That is, you should be able to spin up the application on its production domain or `localhost` or any other domain without conflict. It's the web server's responsibility to sort out IP and hostname related things.

Comment: Seems like a very reasonable point of view.