# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Middleware redirect vs Nginx)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redirect, https

I want to ask about `HTTP-to-HTTPS` redirections. As we know `WWW-to-none-WWW` redirections happen by redirecting from the web server side. But when it comes to the https redirection, it can be done by both ways, server-side (`Nginx etc...`) and application-side (`Middleware`). I want to know:

1. Which of the ways are effective and have more performance.
2. The pros and cons of each way considering multiple `top-level` domains and `sub-domain` domains on the same server.

Thank you.

Reference:

1. [Redirect WWW to non-WWW in Laravel - Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26754119/7396433)
2. [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Laravel - Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28402726/7396433)
3. [HTTP Request To HTTPS on nginx - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-redirect-all-http-to-https/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-based redirection here should be more performant because it happens before any application code gets loaded.

Personally, I always do this in the nginx server{} block for all sites. I create a conf file for a domain and have 2 server{} blocks, a main one listening on 443 for HTTPS traffic, and a small one that just recognises the (sub)domain and does a redirect to the HTTPS protocol.

Here's an example redirect server{} block I have for a particular subdomain:

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    return 301 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

As for pros cons for server-based, the obvious ones I would say are:

#### Pros

- Performance
- Simplicity

#### Cons

- root access required (for nginx at least, Apache you could do it in a .htaccess file, but this in itself has performance costs)
- Can't change things on the fly so easily (flexibility?)

Comment: Great answer. But one question; If I am doing the redirection on the server side, do I need to change anything in my Laravel project (ignoring the third party packages that installed by me) other than changing the `APP_URL` environment variable? the app will change all my routes and URLs to https automatically?

Comment: As long as you're not using complete paths for routes/assets (images/css/js etc) and just using URI paths, eg; `/path/to/something`, then other than `APP_URL` as you note, nothing should need to change (I develop under HTTP but production is always HTTPS).

In regards to assets, _if_ you have specified the (sub)domain of them too, you can just remove the protocol, for example:

`<img src="//sub.domain.com/some-image.png" alt="">`

This will then use the current protocol (HTTP or HTTPS, whatever the site's being accessed as) and load accordingly

Comment: Perfect. I will wait to check if someone else is willing to answer. If I didn't get anything, yours will be accepted. Thanks very much for the completed answer.

Comment: Now, This answer looks more than perfect for me. Thanks.