# Wordpress Social Login -> Post to users Facebook timeline

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, plugins, timeline

I'm currently using this wordpress plugin to be able to login to my website through Facebook:
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-social-login

I'm trying to figure out how exactly I can post a message to a current user's timeline when I click a button on my website.

I read this documentation:
http://miled.github.io/wordpress-social-login/developer-api-apis.html

And it appears you need to include this:

```
include_once( WORDPRESS_SOCIAL_LOGIN_ABS_PATH . '/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php' );
```

Though I keep getting an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found in /home/test.user/git/git_projects/mywebsite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/page.php on line 63, referer: localhost/wp-login.php?action=wordpress_social_authenticate&mode=login&provider=Facebook&redirect_to=localhost/mvp/&refcode=&refcode=&redirect_to_provider=true

Not sure where to go at this point.

Comment: Well, have you look whether the file is located where it should be? Is it accessible?

Comment: I've chmod 777'd and yes I can even access it in the browser.
There must be an easier way to post a message to a current logged in user's wall.

Comment: I've also tried this code:
http://pastebin.com/nSPrkJLn

While it is just a warning, it's not allowing access to Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter('Facebook')

Comment: Did you use google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795216/fatal-error-class-hybrid-logger-not-found-in-hybridauth-hybrid-endpoint-php

Comment: The link given does not appear to have any valid solutions.
session_start() did not solve my problem.