# migrating site to from http to https and SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've been lucky enough in the past when I have to migrate a site from HTTP to HTTPS and install a SSL Cert that I my host does it and everything just works.

I'm working with a host now where I think I will need to be more hands on.

I'm using Wordpress on a Mysql and Apache stack. What would be the proper way to migrate this. Doing a search and replace via the database and then redirects via the .htaccess file?

Currently, I have "https://example.com" working. However, what is the proper way to handle the redirects from www to non-www for both the http and https to "https://example.com". There are Wordpress plugins that "force" SSL but I have heard these can do unexpected things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll explain the procedure without the use of a .htaccess file:
Assuming that you have your wordpress site in place say "http://example.com"

1. Install the ssl certificate (follow the instructions give to you by
   the issuer)
2. Go to your database; wp_options table and change
       'siteurl' and 'home' option value to begin with https instead of
       http and offcourse save the changes.
3. Login to your WordPress admin panel, and go to **Settings** » **General**. Click save Options. This will ensure that the site url is corrected anywhere else that needs to be.
4. Then go to **Settings** » **Permalink** and click Save to ensure that all post links are working fine.
5. Install this plugin [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) and activate. This plugin is supposed to help in fixing images and broken links by updating paths without you having to write code; it's pretty self explanatory.
6. Install this plugin [Easy HTTPS Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/) and activate. This plugin will redirect all traffic from http to https regardless of what; you can also define the pages you don't want forced to https.

And yes I agree with you that WP Force SSL plugin does wonders to a website, I've tried it and I learn't a lesson the hard way, but still I'll try it out. At this point you'll have your "https://example.com" working perfectly

Secondly, I'll explain doing the same procedure without using any plugin. My assumption is same as above.

1. Repeat step 1 and 2 above.
2. Don't leave your database yet, we need to do a search and replace in MySQL using SQL Query. I've listed just a few of things needed to be replaced in the SQL query below

   ```
   UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');

   UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');

   UPDATE wp_postmeta 
   SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');
   ```

   NB: Depending on the tables you have, its always good to do a search and replace per table
3. To redirect from http to https we'll use `.htaccess` file. Try the following with mod_rewrite in your `.htaccess` file

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```

   or any of the various approaches given at

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html

You can also solve this from within PHP in case your provider has disabled `.htaccess` (which is unlikely since you asked for it, but anyway)

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Until this point with both methods https should be working well.

Then, to redirect non-www to www, use the following code directly below RewriteEngine On in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For www to non-www, use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you're on a Windows IIS server, the above code won't work for you. I can share the procedure if need be.

Comment: Great answer and thank you!. I marked accepted. One question. The last part where you are doing the www to non www this can also be done via the cpanel of most hosts with a 301 redirect, correct? Same thing.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Its more fun to use it if you're using a dedicated server; meaning your the king of everything. But still I've seen it in a couple of hosts