# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, devops

How can I redirect my website from https://example.com to https://www.example.com

My website is not working in non www. need to redirect to https://www.example.com format. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to ask your DNS provider for a redirect.

Another way gets explained in this other stackoverflow question: [.htaccess - how to force "www." in a generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way) 
Basically the following should work:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: we are using route53. we cant do in DNS level and more over my site is running on AWS load balancer..

Comment: my example has been for 'http' addresses. Try changing it to 'https'.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect your site from http non-www to https://www you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache as your website, you can use **alias**

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     ServerAlias example.com
>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/devops_blog
>     <Directory /var/www/devops_blog>
>         Options All
>         AllowOverride All
>         Require all granted
>     </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```