# how rewrite to http://www.domian.com/test_site/index.php when url just type "domian.com/test_site"

Tags: php, apache, web, url-rewriting

normal condition
  redirect to "`http://www.domain.com`" when just type "`domain.com`"

## we can use like below on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

=================================================================
if anyone know when use append folder to be a website ?
how to set rule on .htaccess?

if  i want to just type   "`domain.com/uat_01`" hope redirect to 
 "`http://www.domain.com/uat_01`"  or   `"http://www.domain.com/uat_01/index.php"`

Comment: You don't need to worry about rewriting the HTTP bit - when they request `domain.com/uat_01` it *must* be over HTTP (or HTTPS) already. I think all you need to rewrite is forcing the `www` to display? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way) for how to do that.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: you totally help my perfect to  solve my problem     !!    the code is so beauty and clean!!